# How to count viewcount of a video

Tags: video, youtube

I am creating a video site having videos entered by users. But i want to show viewcount of a each video along with it as in Youtube. How it is achievable ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of many things:

- Add your own code that increases a value in a database each time the video is access
- Create a record in a database table for each view then count rows
- Use an off the shelve counter like [hitcounter](http://www.supercounters.com/hitcounter) (among others)
- ...

Comment: actually i have flash player to play my video...so according to our first suggestion if some one plays video then i have to pass value from flash player to my server side scripting...?

Comment: You don't need to pass a value, just invoke some "addView" method/service